# Google Sheets Google Forms updates

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a Google Form for which collects data from a user.  Once the use submits the form I have scripts that copy the data to several other Google sheets and then send an email to the appropriate people with the data. This works well.  However, when the user edits the form it updates the data in the Form Responses 1 tab correctly but a new row is added to the other sheets.  I want to be able to just update the appropriate row/cells in the other sheets, not create a new row because I have two rows addressing the same info.

I have tried saving the URL of the form, i.e., the edit URL, to each of the target sheets so I can match on it later but,

1. There seems to be a significant delay for the edit URL to be populated in the Form Response 1 tab so the copy fails because at the time of the copy the URL is not there.
2. how can I determine if the response is from an edited form not a new response?

I am rather new to this so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> how can I determine if the response is from an edited form not a new response?

If you are using the Google Sheets on form submit trigger `e.namedValues.Timestamp` will return `undefined` when a form submission corresponds to a form response edit.

The above because the properties `values` and `namedValues` will only include the edited responses, i.e. the timestamp will not be included as it corresponds to the original form submission.

NOTE: the range property will point to a row that might not be the last row.

Related

- [How to check if current submission is editing response or a new response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475536/1595451) (Stack Overflow)